# window.open() after long process in Worker is detected as Popup

Tags: javascript, popup, window.open, worker

Hi i want to open a new tab after long process in the Worker (take 5-6 seconds), but its detected like a Popup. My code:

```
--MAIN--
<button onclick="startWorker()">Start Worker</button> 

function startWorker() {
    if(typeof(Worker) !== "undefined") {

        if(typeof(w) == "undefined") {
            w = new Worker("Worker.js");
        }

        w.onmessage = function(event) {
            window.open(event.data);
        };  
}


--Worker.js--

        //Do something
        postMessage("http://google.com");
```

- Then it occurred to me, to execute the Window.open() command from Worker.js but this freezes in browser.

Is there a method to call the Main script and execute the command window.open ()? Like: 
`Main.window.open("something");`

- The other possible way that occurred to me was to call the function from window.open and return the desired link. But this does not work, it returns -> undefined... Code:
  `Window.open(startWorker());`

Thanks you!

Comment: A worker does not execute on the main thread, as such it's doesn't know anything about GUI, that's why you have to use messages.  You can't really stop the popup blockers, otherwise every dubious website would use this feature.  Your best bet it to either ask your users to add an exception, or open the page inside an IFrame.

Comment: you can have the worked launch a modal alert that says something like "xxx is ready -[ok]" where a click() on `[ok]` launches the window without it being detected as a popup, since it's the result of a user action.